# How to select the row value based on preference order in the table using MySql

Tags: mysql

I have table as data_attributes with a column data_type

```
SELECT * FROM DATA_ATTRIBUTES;

DATA_TYPE
----------
NAME
MOBILE
ETHINICITY
CC_INFO
BANK_INFO
ADDRESS
```

Bank_info, CC_info classified as Risk1,

Mobile, Ethinicity classified as Risk2,

Name, Address classified as Risk3

I should get the Risk classification as output,

For eg: If any of the row contains Risk1 type then output should be Risk1,
else if any of the row contains Risk2 type then  output should be Risk2,
else if any of the row contains Risk3 type then  output should be Risk3

I wrote below query for this

```
SELECT COALESCE(COL1,COL2,COL3) FROM
(SELECT 
CASE WHEN DATATYPE IN ('BANK_INFO','CC_INFO') THEN 'RISK1' ELSE NULL END AS COL1, 
CASE WHEN DATATYPE IN ('MOBILE','ETHINICITY') THEN 'RISK2' ELSE NULL END AS COL2,
CASE WHEN DATATYPE IN ('NAME','ADDRESS') THEN 'RISK3' ELSE NULL END AS COL3
FROM DEMO.TPA_CLASS1) A;
```

The required output is: Risk1  ( Only 1 value )

Please give some idea to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN MAX(DATATYPE IN ('BANK_INFO','CC_INFO')) = 1 THEN 'RISK1'
    WHEN MAX(DATATYPE IN ('MOBILE','ETHINICITY')) = 1 THEN 'RISK2'
    WHEN MAX(DATATYPE IN ('NAME','ADDRESS')) = 1 THEN 'RISK3'
  END AS RISK
FROM DEMO.TPA_CLASS
```